# Adding json string at the end after URL

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I having a Json values,

```
{"menu": {
  "apiurl":"www.google.com",
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()", id: "1"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()", id: "2"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()", id: "3}
    ]
  }
}}
```

and passing one url like,

let htmlurl = "www.google.com"

now i need to add all id's separate by comma (",") to end of url, like this "www.google.com/1,2,3".

I need answer in angular2 using typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ids = obj.menu.popup.menuitem.map(item => item.id); // ["1", "2", "3"]
const url = 'www.google.com/' + ids.join(','); // "www.google.com/1,2,3"
```

Comment: I would think you'd need to encode that url for it to actually work. No?